# Does Lync 2010 or 2013 store the user's presence history?

Tags: lync, lync-2010, lync-server-2010, lync-2013

I would like to know if Lync 2010 or 2013 store the user's presence history (like the user was available at a particular time and was away at particular time") in the client application or at the backend server(logs).??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it might be possible, but you would have to essentially add your own database trigger to record the historical data. There are also tools that may make it a bit easier as mentioned here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/8212257e-03ba-4791-8eb9-14c7685b452f/how-to-get-user-presence-data-from-the-lync-2010-sql-server-dbs?forum=ocspresenceim